# execute parameterized liquibase changeset multiple times with different parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I have been struggling with a liquibase challenge for some time and I hope somebody here can help me:

I would like to execute a simple parameterized liquibase script multiple times on the same db schema with different parameters:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="me" dbms="Oracle" runOnChange="false" failOnError="true">

   <sql splitStatements="true">
      GRANT SELECT on SOME_VIEW to ${db_user};
   </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Now I execute liquibase one time with -Ddb_user=first_user and than with -Ddb_user=second_user. The second run fails, because liquibase calculates the checkSum after replacing the ${db_user} parameter (what makes perfect sense) and therefore the combination of id/author/filename and checkSum is already present in the DATABASECHANGELOG table.

Is there a best practice way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `runOnChange` as an attribute for the [`changeSet`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html) which will run your changeset each time it was changed. Maybe this does what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `runOnChange=true` or `<validCheckSum>any</validCheckSum>`

There is an issue that explains this decision here: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2506